# Azure - Data Management Gateway - Endpoint Error

Tags: azure, gateway, cloud-computing

Has anybody tried to setup this Data Management Gateway on-premise with Azure Data Factory? I am following this guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud

It all goes well but when I have the gateway installed. it shows an error under *Settings* tab - *Endpoint* section - *Status: Error*. when I hover over the error, it states:

```
Failed to retrieve the status of ssl certificate. you can correct this by adding the user to the Data Management Gateway Users group or restarting the machine that has the gateway
```

Has anybody experienced the same issue? I have selected a SSL certificate that we are using within this domain with no problem and the Data Management Gateway user group has access for this certificate.

Anybody any ideas how to get rid of this?